# Error with using create method with HTTPS Post request [ReactJs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

so I have recently been working on an admin control panel for a page that displays a list of cards (Some video and some text-based). I am hosting a local API that generates 7 different unique posts of data (these include the post's id, title, url, thumbnailUrl). I have managed to create 2 seperate methods, one of being a delete card and the other being an edit card button. I am now trying to add a "Create" button that opens up a modal popup with empty fields that allows for the admin user to insert it, and once create is clicked, a new data field is added to the API's database.

The code below is for the HelpList.tsx (This is responsible for displaying the list of cards) module created which contains the deleteProduct, editProduct and createProduct methods. I have tried to base my createProduct function on the editProduct one, although I'm unsure if the function will know how to give the card / post an incremented and appropriate Id.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HelpCard from "./HelpCard";
import "../help/HelpCard.css";
import axios from "axios";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroller";
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";

interface State {
  url: string;
  title: string;
  adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard[];
  error: null;
  response: {};
  thumbnail: string;
}

interface SingleAdminHelpCard {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
}

interface Props {
  //createProduct: (title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) => void;
}

export default class HelpList extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    title: "",
    thumbnail: "",
    id: "",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/videos/",
    adminhelpcard: [],
    itemsCountPerPage: 1,
    activePage: 1,
    error: null,
    response: {}
    //isEditProduct: true,
    //isAddProduct: true
  };

  loadAdminHelpCard = () => {
    axios
      .get(this.state.url)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          const adminhelpcard = prevState.adminhelpcard;
          return {
            adminhelpcard: [...prevState.adminhelpcard, ...res.data],
            url: res.data.next
          };
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  static props: any;

  async componentDidMount() {
    const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/videos/";
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({ adminhelpcard: res.data });
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            adminhelpcard: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }

  deleteProduct(id: any) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;

    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`;

    const options = {
      method: "DELETE"
    };

    fetch(apiUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );

    console.log(this.state.id);
  }

  editProduct(id: any, title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;
    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`;

    const options = {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        url,
        thumbnail
      })
    };

    fetch(apiUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }

  createProduct(title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) {
    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/`;

    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        url,
        thumbnail
      })
    };

    fetch(apiUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.adminhelpcard);
    return (
      <div>
        <React.Fragment>
          {this.state.adminhelpcard ? (
            <div className="row">
              <InfiniteScroll
                pageStart={1}
                loadMore={this.loadAdminHelpCard}
                hasMore={this.state.url ? true : false}
                threshold={0}
                loader={
                  <div className="loader" key={0}>
                    Loading ...
                  </div>
                }>
                {this.state.adminhelpcard.map((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard, i) => (
                  <HelpCard
                    id={adminhelpcard.id}
                    key={adminhelpcard.id + i}
                    title={adminhelpcard.title}
                    url={adminhelpcard.url}
                    thumbnail={adminhelpcard.thumbnail}
                    deleteProduct={this.deleteProduct.bind(this)}
                    editProduct={this.editProduct.bind(this)}
                  />
                ))}
              </InfiniteScroll>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <h1>Loading Cards</h1>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am then calling the editProduct and deleteProduct functions within buttons that are available in the HelpCard.tsx which is responsible for generating the structure of the card itself.

The code below is for the videoCard which also contains the  component (modal tooltip) that contains the editProduct fields and functions:

```
<div className="horizontalCard">
              <div className="innerCard">
                <div className="leftImage">
                  <img
                    className="Sprite"
                    onLoad={() => this.setState({ imageLoading: false })}
                    onError={() => this.setState({ tooManyRequests: true })}
                    src={this.state.thumbnail}
                    style={
                      this.state.tooManyRequests
                        ? { display: "none" }
                        : this.state.imageLoading
                        ? { display: "null" }
                        : { display: "null" }
                    }
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="rightText">
                  <div className="card-body">
                    {this.state.title}
                    <div className="cardButtons">
                      <Popup trigger={<button className="btn">Edit</button>} position="left center">
                        <form
                          onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                          id="videoCardEdit"
                          style={{ width: "auto", height: "auto" }}>
                          <div>
                            <div>
                              <label>Title:</label>
                              <input
                                name="videoCardTitle"
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                  this.setState({ title: e.target.value });
                                }}
                                value={this.state.title}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <label>URL:</label>
                              <input
                                name="videoCardURL"
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                  this.setState({ url: e.target.value });
                                }}
                                value={this.state.url}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <label>Thumbnail URL:</label>
                              <input
                                name="videoCardThumbnail"
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                  this.setState({ thumbnail: e.target.value });
                                }}
                                value={this.state.thumbnail}></input>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <button
                            className="btnConfirm"
                            style={{
                              float: "left"
                            }}
                            onClick={() =>
                              this.props.editProduct(
                                this.props.id,
                                this.state.title,
                                this.state.url,
                                this.state.thumbnail
                              )
                            }
                            id="confirmModalBtn">
                            confirm
                          </button>
                        </form>
                      </Popup>
                      <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteProduct(this.props.id)} className="btn">
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Finally, I am then inserting the "Create" button within my HelpAdmin.view.tsx page (This is more or less my index.tsx / app.tsx for this task, since I am displaying my list and button within this panel page). I am trying to implement the Create button so that it is displayed on top of the  component that is created. The code for the following page is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HelpList from "../components/helpAdmin/help/HelpList";
import "../components/helpAdmin/help/HelpList";

import Popup from "reactjs-popup";


interface Props {
  createProduct: (title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) => void;
}

interface State {
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
  id: string;
  url: string;
}

export class HelpAdminView extends Component<Props, State> {
  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <div className="box">
          <Popup trigger={<button className="btn"> Create a new card</button>} position="right center">
            <div>
              <div>
                <label>Title:</label>
                <input
                  name="createCardTitle"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ title: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  value={this.state.title}></input>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>URL:</label>
                <input
                  name="createCardURL"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ url: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  value={this.state.url}></input>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>Thumbnail URL:</label>
                <input
                  name="createCardThumbnail"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ thumbnail: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  value={this.state.thumbnail}></input>
              </div>

              <button
                style={{
                  float: "left"
                }}
                onClick={() => this.props.createProduct(this.state.title, this.state.url, this.state.thumbnail)}
                className="btnCreate"
                id="confirmModalBtn">
                Create
              </button>
            </div>
          </Popup>
          <HelpList />
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
export default HelpAdminView;
```

This code seems to constantly throw me the following error when trying to run the project and it is as follows:

```
Type error: Property 'createProduct' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly<Props>'.  TS2741
```

I am unsure as to why this error is being thrown even though I've tried to call this function the same way I've tried to call the previously working ones. IS there something I am clearly missing over here?

Thank you for any help in advance!

------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------

The following code is the interface props available within the HelpCard.Tsx The functions are then called as shown in the onClick code above.:

```
interface Props {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
  deleteProduct: (id: any) => void;
  editProduct: (id: any, title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) => void;
}
```

Comment: where are you using the HelpAdminView component  and passing the prop ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai I am calling the HelpAdminView in my App.tsx <switch> component. <Route path="/help-admin" render={() => <HelpAdminView />} />

Answer (score 0):

`HelpAdminView` component requires `createProduct` as its `props` because it is a required prop. While calling the same `<HelpAdminView />` there is no prop passed that is why this type error is thrown.
We cannot access another component's methods by including the component. In this case, you are including `HelpList` and trying to access the methods defined there.

Comment: If by this, you mean to add this code to the interface Props of the HelpList.tsx module, then I have also already tried this. and the same error is thrown at me.

Comment: Also, I've I move the <Popup> buttom to the HelpList page, or add the interface Props to the HelpAdmin.view.Tsx, then the following error is given on the onclick segment of the code "this.props.createProduct" which is as follows

Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)

Comment: Also, can you share from where VideoCard component is getting called and how editProduct is passed as a prop to it.

Comment: I have added the props interface which is how I'm giving the other functions to it.  I have tried doing the exact same thing with this createProduct, tried to call it the same way I did with the others but the error is still thrown.

Comment: Can you share HelpCard's usage? Because in this case editProduct and deleteProduct should be passed as props to HelpCard to work.